# web3.eth.contract - Unexpected types

Tags: python, blockchain

Хочу сделать скрипт для взаимодействия с контрактом. Не могу понять почему web3.eth.contract ругается на тип данных, делаю все как в туториалах. Пишу в pycharm. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что ему нужно?

address и abi становятся красными с ошибкой:

> Unexpected type(s):  (str, str)
> Possible type(s):
> (None, Any)
> (Union[Address, ChecksumAddress, ENS], Any)

```
import json

from web3 import Web3

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

contract_address = "0x0000e942F814380000D706f900000848501F0000"
abi = json.loads('[{...}]')

contract = web3.eth.contract(address='contract_address', abi='abi')
```

Comment: Я не спец по Питону, но - оно там точно в апострофах должно быть: web3.eth.contract(address='contract_address', abi='abi')? Вот тут - без них - https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html

Comment: @MadJackal Спасибо, что ответили, но разницы никакой, пробовал по разному